# NextJS routeChangeComplete doesn't trigger on _app.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

Here my ReactJS' snippet:

```
 const LoaderModal = dynamic(
    () => import("~/modal/Loader/Loader"),
    { ssr: false }
 )
     export default class MyApp extends Component {
state={
displayLoader:false
}
componentDidMount(){
    let specificChangeStart= Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => {
        console.log("routeChangeStart")
        this.setState({displayLoader:true})
    })
    let specificComplete = Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
        console.log("routeChangeComplete")
        this.setState({displayLoader:false})
    })
    let specificError= Router.events.on('routeChangeError',() => {
        console.log("routeChangeError")
        this.setState({displayLoader:false})
    })
}
render(){
    let { Component, pageProps }=this.props
    let {displayLoader}=this.state
      return(
          <LayoutContextProvider >    
              <Component {...pageProps}/>
              {
                  displayLoader &&
                      <LoaderModal/>
              }
          </LayoutContextProvider>
      )
  }
}
```

I am using nextjs version 9.1.4.

As you can see the Router's events are stored in the componentDidMount() component lifecycle's stage. I have stored them in variable to make them specific from other declarations in my app. I have also tried without assigning them, the both method fail so far.

How can I make the Router works, is there a subtlety to be inform of here?

Comment: You've set it to a variable instead of just invoking `Router.events.on(...)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer @MattCarlotta, as I have said, "I have also tried without assigning them, the both method fail so far."

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example either from a github repo or from a [NextJS codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/).

Comment: Also, you've said: `I have stored them in variable to make them specific from other declarations in my app`. Why? These are confined within their respective components, so it's unnecessary to set them to variables (also, you haven't invoked them: `specificError();`, so they're never registered). Also, are you [unregistering (scroll to bottom)](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents) them when a component is unmounted? For example, `Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', ...)`? A working example should help answer these questions.

Comment: @MattCarlotta thanks for the informations. I will provide a github repo in the next twenty minutes.

Comment: the minimal reproduction works well, so seems it is an another problem from other point of my app that just the router implementation itself. I will explore and effectively unregistering them.

Comment: @MattCarlotta yes it works by unregistering the different `Router.events`' listeners in my app. I have tried now even with assigning them to variable, both work. Your assist is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to track down the issue.